# To Socks or not to socks?

Tags: toddler, daycare, clothes

My own daughter mostly refused to wear socks - unless she had shoes on - until she was about five years old.  Even now, she only wears them in the coldest months and rips them off her feet at the drop of a hat.

The three-year-old I now watch is pretty much the same way.  With my own daughter, we had carpets and since the weather is pretty warm about ten months out of the year, I didn't worry about it too much and just kept her in sandals for outside.

However, with the young man I am caring for, his feet are always cold - even the rest of him seems fairly warm.  I worry that his little feet are getting too cold.  Should I be concerned, or just let him be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As an adult who rarely wear socks without shoes I'd say either leave him and at three he'll let you know if it bothers him even if it's indirectly.

So long as his body temperature is fine then there's unlikely to be any cause for concern.

Comment: At 3, he should certainly be able to tell you if his feet are cold.  I don't wear socks much and neither do my kids--the only person in my house who wears socks consistently is my husband who was born and raised in a cold climate.  The rest of us spend most of our time barefoot.

Comment: Thanks Meg - The reason for saying that signs might be indirect is because kids often don't notice things that happen gradually.  Think of it like knowing when they need the loo; it's not until you ask that they realise they *really* need to go.

Comment: Thanks @JamesSnell.  I can't tell you how many kids I've cared for, students I've taught, and times I've looked at a kid of any age and thought, "you are ____ right now" and its like the kid doesn't know it until you say, "are you ___ right now?"  Especially at three.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a sensory problem?  As in, do socks feel too tight to him?  Maybe a pair of slip-on slippers or jandals might help.  But as others say above, he should be able to let you know if he's cold.